# Image upload, not recognising file extension

Tags: php, forms, apache, post, upload

I have used this tutorial to build an image uploader.

http://www.codeforest.net/upload-crop-and-resize-images-with-php

This uses the library

https://gist.github.com/philBrown/880506/download#

However, when ever I pass a file to it via the form, it always fails on the last IF statement (please upload an image)

Below is the code :

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ImageManipulator.php');

if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] . "<br />";
} else {
    // array of valid extensions
    $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.JPG', '.JPEG', '.PNG', '.GIF', '.bmp');
    // get extension of the uploaded file
    $fileExtension = strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], ".");
    // check if file Extension is on the list of allowed ones
    if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {
        $newNamePrefix = time() . '_';
        $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        $width  = $manipulator->getWidth();
        $height = $manipulator->getHeight();
        $centreX = round($width / 2);
        $centreY = round($height / 2);
        // our dimensions will be 80by80
        $x1 = $centreX - 40; // 80
        $y1 = $centreY - 40; // 80

        $x2 = $centreX + 40; // 80
        $y2 = $centreY + 40; // 80

        // center cropping to 80by80
        $newImage = $manipulator->crop($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
        // saving file to uploads folder
        $manipulator->save('/images/avatars/uploaded/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
        echo 'Done ...';
    } else {
        echo 'You must upload an image...';
    }
}
?>
```

And here is the form.

```
<h4>Change Avatar</h4>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/lib/uploadimage.php"><table class="table table-striped">
   <tr><td>Please choose a file:</td><td><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
   <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Upload"></td></tr>
   </table></form>
```

I plan on once I have this working, inserting the URL into a database.

I'm assuming it fails on the upload side of things, however the apache logs don't give me any errors and also the folder has 757 permissions.

Any idea why this is failing?

EDIT: The error via apache is

```
log:[Sat Jul 19 20:48:51 2014] [error] [client 82.46.57.58] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fileToUpload in /var/SITE/lib/uploadimage.php on line 5, referer: SITE/index.php
```

EDIT: Digging deeper, it seems to be a permission issue

```
SITE:[Sat Jul 19 21:31:58 2014] [error] [client 82.46.57.58] PHP   2. ImageManipulator->save() /SITE/lib/uploadimage.php:30, referer: SITE/index.php
SITE:[Sat Jul 19 21:31:58 2014] [error] [client 82.46.57.58] PHP   3. mkdir() /SITE/lib/ImageManipulator.php:222, referer: SITE/index.php
SITE:[Sat Jul 19 21:31:58 2014] [error] [client 82.46.57.58] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Error creating directory /images/avatars/uploaded' in /SITE/lib/ImageManipulator.php:223\nStack trace:\n#0 /SITE/lib/uploadimage.php(30): ImageManipulator->save('/images/avatars...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /SITE/lib/ImageManipulator.php on line 223, referer: SITE/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It was permission based and a small error in the image directory.

It should of been ../images, and folder needed to be owned by www-data.